# explanation about SqlSessionFactory

Tags: spring, orm, mapping, mybatis

I'm new in MyBatis and Spring. I'm trying to understand the puzzle between these frameworks.

I haven't found a real documentation on SqlSessionFactory.

My question is: what exactly does SqlSessionFactory and within the flow between the DB and the logic at what point is it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The primary Java interface for working with MyBatis is the SqlSession.
>   Through this interface you can execute commands, get mappers and
>   manage transactions.
>   SqlSessions are created by a SqlSessionFactory instance. The
>   SqlSessionFactory contains methods for creating instances of
>   SqlSessions all different ways. The SqlSessionFactory itself is
>   created by the SqlSessionFactoryBuilder that can create the
>   SqlSessonFactory from XML, Annotations or hand coded Java
>   configuration.

You can check the documentation for more info

[SqlSessionFactory](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/java-api.html)

[SqlSessionFactoryBean](http://mybatis.github.io/spring/factorybean.html)

Check also these 2 links which explain the Spring-Mybatis Integration.

[Spring&MyBatis](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/spring-mybatis-integration-example/)

[Spring&MyBatis2](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/02/building-java-web-application-using-mybatis-with-spring.html)

The DB-logic connection takes place in the MyBatis xml files.

[SQLMapper](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html)

Comment: Thank you. I've read them before, but I'm looking for a personal explanation.